# Nexys2 - any luck getting it running on a virtual machine?

Tags: fpga, spartan, ise

So I have a Nexys2 500K board that works when connected 'directly into the os', when I'm running Win7. However, as I use Mac OS X (10.8.2) mainly, I don't want to reboot my PC just to use the board for a moment. So I made a virtual machine (V: VirtualBox), and I set an USB filter to automatically connect a device with

```
Product ID: 0x0005
Vendor ID:  0x1443
```

However, although iMPACT and adept detect the board as Nexys2, they always fail to initialize chain with following error (from iMPACT)

```
GUI --- Auto connect to cable...
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: Plugin Version: 2.4.4 INFO:iMPACT -
Digilent Plugin: found 1 device(s).
INFO:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: opening device: "Nexys2",
SN:10054D236487 ERROR:iMPACT - Digilent Plugin: failed to open device (DmgrOpen, erc = 3072).
AutoDetecting cable. Please wait.
*** WARNING ***: When port is set to auto detect mode, cable speed is 
set to default 6 MHz regardless of explicit arguments supplied for setting the baud rates PROGRESS_START - Starting Operation.
Connecting to cable (Usb Port - USB21).
Checking cable driver.
Source driver files not found.
The Platform Cable USB is not detected. Please connect a cable.If a 
cable is connected, please disconnect and reconnect to the usb port, 
follow the instructions in the 'Found New Hardware Wizard', then retry the Cable Setup operation.
```

I tried installing the cable drivers from digilent site, but for some reason, Impact cannot detect them (I can only see those two default cable drivers from xilinx).

So, anybody had found a way to get it running through a virtual machine? (Tried installing ISE on Win7, Win8, and newest CentOS, all can't detect anything)

Comment: Any chance this works by downloading firmware to a USB micro then re-enumerating as a different device?  If so, perhaps you only assigned the firmware loading device to the VM, and not the one seen after the firmware download.  Do you have any oddball usb devices showing up in OSX?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late reply but since I spent my whole day today trying to get this setup to work, I wanted to spare someone else the effort.
In short, the digilent tools communicate neither under OSX10.6.8, OSX10.9.4 nor under Win 8.1 -- with virtualbox that is (I used 4.3.14)

Turns out that this is a [known limitation of virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/1347) that persists since 2008.

FWIW, I have it now working using vmware player (using Win8.1) - it's is marginally slower than running on native Windows but it works quite well.